# validation error message not showing for min length when custom validation directive added

Tags: angularjs

I want to show error message when the length is lesser than 5, I have tried something like this but its never showing error message "Length must be greated than 5". It works when I remove the attribute equals-to from input tag. How to fix the directive so that its ok with minlength and other validation attributes

```
<form id="createUserForm" class="form-horizontal row row-full" role="form" name="userForm" novalidate>    
...
<input id="newPassword" name="newPassword" ng-model="newPassword" type="password" ng-minlength="5" equals-to="confirmPassword">
    <label ng-show="userForm.newPassword.minlength" class="error">Length must be greater than 4</label>
...
</form>
```

javascript

```
.directive('equalsTo', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                if (viewValue === scope[attrs.equalsTo]) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', true);
                    return viewValue;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', false);
                    return undefined;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: How is `userForm.user.newPassword.minlength` defined?

Comment: @TimCastelijns question updated

Answer (score 0):

You should check `userForm.newPassword.$error.minlength`, because ngMinlength sets `minlength` key to `$error` object.